# IP tuntap command can't open tun

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I want to create a TUN interfae
I type command in adb like below

```
mkdir -p /dev/net
busybox mknod /dev/net/tun1 c 10 200
chmod 666 /dev/net/tun1
ip tuntap add dev tun1 mode tun
```

When I type "ip tuntap add dev tun1 mode tun"
It show "open: No such file or directory"
like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2NwF.jpg

Can anyone give me some idea? 
It's about kernel or other?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Before creating TUN interface, you should create symlink because `ip tuntap` expected `tun` to be in `/dev/net/tun`. Here is the command:

```
ln -s /dev/net/tun /dev/tun
```

Comment: The arguments order is wrong, as stated in other answers. Note: If you tried this first then the other way around, its all messed up and you should reboot to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

as root run

```sh
mkdir /dev/net
ln -s /dev/tun /dev/net/tun
```

Jacob's answer had the arguments order wrong. I do not have enough rep to comment on his answer so I had to write this one.

Answer (score 0):

if the answers about symbolic links didn't help, try

```
modprobe tun
```